# Calculate pandas groupby difference iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, diff

Hi I created a column called "group" based on if the row before and after is fruit.

How could I create the new_group column? It's based on 10-minute fruit gaps. The dataframe is sorted by person, time.

```
person   time_bought  product  group  new_group
abby     2:21         fruit     1       1
abby     2:24         other     
abby     2:25         fruit     2       1  (2.25 is within 10 minutes of 2.21 so part of same group)
abby     10:35        fruit     2       2  
abby     10:40        other
abby     10:42        fruit     3       2  (10.42 is within 10 minutes of 10.35)
abby     10:53        fruit     4       3  (10.53 is not within 10 minutes of 10.42)
abby     11:04        fruit     d
barry    12:00        fruit     1
```

I tried

```
m= df.groupby(["person", "group"]).time_bought.diff()
df["new_group"] = df.groupby(["person, "group"]).mask(m).ffill()
```

Comment: what if you had a row '10:46' after '10:42', would it be part of group 2?

Comment: 10.46 is within 10 minutes of 10.42 so it would be part of group 2 yes

Comment: can you detail how you want to mask? For instance the first row doesn't have a preceding "fruit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate your new group, you can use:

```
m1 = pd.to_datetime(df['time_bought']).groupby(df['person']).diff().gt('10min')
df['new_group'] = m1.cumsum().add(1)
```

output:

```
  person time_bought product group  new_group
0   abby        2:21   fruit     1          1
1   abby        2:24   other  None          1
2   abby        2:25   fruit     2          1
3   abby       10:35   fruit     2          2
4   abby       10:40   other  None          2
5   abby       10:42   fruit     3          2
6   abby       10:53   fruit     4          3
7   abby       11:04   fruit     d          4
8  barry       12:00   fruit     1          4
```

Potential masking: mask non-fruit and last of group (the logic is unclear):

```
m2 = df['product'].ne('fruit')
m3 = df['person'].ne(df['person'].shift(-1))
df['new_group'] = m1.cumsum().add(1).mask(m2|m3).convert_dtypes()
```

output:

```
  person time_bought product group  new_group
0   abby        2:21   fruit     1          1
1   abby        2:24   other  None       <NA>
2   abby        2:25   fruit     2          1
3   abby       10:35   fruit     2          2
4   abby       10:40   other  None       <NA>
5   abby       10:42   fruit     3          2
6   abby       10:53   fruit     4          3
7   abby       11:04   fruit     d       <NA>
8  barry       12:00   fruit     1       <NA>
```

Comment: Not sure this works because the difference being within 10 minutes calculation needs to be conditional only on the product being fruit.

Comment: can you give a counter-example? One can also exclude the non-fruits to make the groups: `pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['product'].eq('fruit'), 'time_bought']).groupby(df['person']).diff().gt('10min')`

Comment: Why is this sensitive to whether I reset the data frame before running the solution even if I still sort the data frame?